# Getting Read-only excel using python

Tags: python

I am trying to read an already existing excel file, and append some data in another sheet in that excel file. however, after closing the file, when i try to manually open it and do some manual calculation etc.. it's says that excel is read-only. can you please help me.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os, glob
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
from openpyxl import load_workbook

ticker = "SBIN.NS"
start = dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(5000)
end = dt.datetime.today()
ohlcv_data = pd.DataFrame()
temp_ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
ohlcv_data = temp_ticker.history(start=start,end=end,interval='1d')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:/NSE/SBI.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',mode='a')
ohlcv_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='yahoo_data2')    
writer.close()
```

Comment: Change the file mode after writing to the file

Comment: Calling `.close()` does not seem to be enough. Until the Python process exits, the Excel itself cannot write to the file.